# Add extra field in existing table

Tags: magento-1.8

I added following codes in my **app\code\local\Svi\Form\sql\form_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('svi_form')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('svi_form')} (
  `form_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `fathername` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `mothername` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `mobile` bigint(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`form_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ") or die("error in local/svi/form/sql folder.....");


 //Add new column to the 'svi_form' table

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $this->getTable('svi/form'), //table name
        'address' 'varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '''  //'column name' 

//datatype definition

        );

$installer->endSetup();
```

**app\code\local\Svi\Form\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Svi_Form>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Svi_Form>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <form>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Svi_Form</module>
                    <frontName>form</frontName>
                </args>
            </form>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <form>
                    <file>form.xml</file>
                </form>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <form>
                <class>Svi_Form_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>form_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </form>
            <form_mysql4>
                <class>Svi_Form_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <form>
                        <table>svi_form</table>
                    </form>
                </entities>
            </form_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <form_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Svi_Form</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </form_setup>
            <form_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </form_write>
            <form_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </form_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <form>
                <class>Svi_Form_Block</class>
            </form>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <form>
                <class>Svi_Form_Helper</class>
            </form>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

But it is not working. What to do?

Comment: show your config.xml file

Comment: this code " $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(..." u add after run your script ??

Comment: @ND17 table is already in database. but when i added code for new field. I didn't get new field. what to do? can you explain your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want to update your module in terms of new database fields to provide new functionality, you need to alter your schema, change fields datatypes, introduce new columns, and so on.

This is when the upgrade script comes in handy. You can not make any direct changes via an SQL editor by running row queries, because whenever another user installs your module, that new database change will not work in their setup. It’s Magento’s recommendation to use an upgrade script for altering the database schema.

An upgrade script is similar to an install script – the only change is the name and a different version number.

we will create an upgrade script named **mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php** under `app\code\local\Svi\Form\sql\form_setup\`. Add the following code.

```
  <?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('form/form'),//table name 

    'address',      //column name
    'varchar(255) NOT NULL'  //datatype definition
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

change in config.xml

```
 <modules>
    <Svi_Form>
        <version>0.1.1</version> // here 0.1.0 to 0.1.1
    </Svi_Form>
</modules>
```

Comment: Hey dude, I have to create new file when i will change version of sql file?

Comment: yes u have to create new file and change version

Comment: Hey dude, when i will create new file of sql then only above code have to put there or some other code should be there?

Comment: noo bt make sure u will change version in config.xml

Comment: I did dude as you said here but it is not working....

Comment: is there any error? and make sure that your new file name suppose this  mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php  than u have to write version this 0.1.1

Comment: no dude there is no error.....

Comment: wait I am posting here what i did.

Comment: hey change this $this->getTable('form/form') replace svi with form

Comment: I changed to svi from form but till now not working.

Comment: you are so caring person,  thanks for your effort......

Comment: ok in database find table  "core_resource" in that find "form_setup" and tell me the version

Comment: Hey dude there is 0.1.1 in "form_setup"

Comment: than change it to 0.1.0 in both column and than refresh ur website page

Comment: Accepted and also gave you reputation.

Answer (score 1):

**I created new file in app\code\local\Svi\Form\sql\form_setup\mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('form/form'),//table name
    'address',      //column name
    'varchar(255) NOT NULL'  //datatype definition
    );
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

**and change the version in app\code\local\Svi\Form\etc\config.xml**

```
<modules>
    <Svi_Form>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </Svi_Form>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade script is similar to an install script – the only change is the name and a different version number.

example:
create an upgrade script named mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $this->getTable('test/test'),//table name 

    'address',      //column name
    'varchar(255) NOT NULL'  //datatype definition
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

change in config.xml

```
 <modules>
    <Svi_Form>
        <version>0.1.1</version> // here 0.1.0 to 0.1.1
    </Svi_Form>
</modules>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$sql = <<<SQLTEXT
ALTER TABLE `YOUR_tABLE_NAME` ADD `COLUMN_NAME` VARCHAR( 500 ) 
SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);

$installer->endSetup();
```